# Importing data from Oracle into Hive using SQOOP

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

We are trying to import data from an Oracle DB into Hive, but hitting a CLASSNOTFOUND exception.

Version of Hadoop is:

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.5.1
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 2e18d179e4a8065b6a9f29cf2de9451891265cce
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-09-05T23:11Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 6424fcab95bfff8337780a181ad7c78
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.5.1.jar
```

Version of Scoop is:

```
$ ./sqoop-version
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
15/02/17 16:10:51 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5
Sqoop 1.4.5
git commit id 5b34accaca7de251fc91161733f906af2eddbe83
Compiled by abe on Fri Aug  1 11:19:26 PDT 2014
```

Class Path is set

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
:/home/huser/data-integration/lib:/home/huser/data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin:/home/huser/data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/lib:/home/huser/data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/hadoop-20:/home/huser/data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/hadoop-20/lib:/home/huser/data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/hadoop-20/lib/client:/usr/local/sqoop/lib:/usr/local/sqoop/lib
```

SQOOP COMMAND:

```
sqoop import -libjars=/usr/local/sqoop/lib/ojdbc7.jar --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@SOME_IP:1521:orcl --table PRODUCT_DETAILS  --target-dir /tmp/hive-huser/test --split-by <coulmn-name> --username <username> --password <password> --verbose --bindir "/usr/local/sqoop/class/"
```

The error we are receiving is :

```
15/02/17 15:11:18 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1789263485_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class PRODUCT_DETAILS not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class PRODUCT_DETAILS not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1905)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getInputClass(DBConfiguration.java:403)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopDataDrivenDBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader(OraOopDataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:187)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.createRecordReader(DBInputFormat.java:263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:492)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:735)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class PRODUCT_DETAILS not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1811)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1903)
        ... 12 more
15/02/17 15:11:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1789263485_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
15/02/17 15:11:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
15/02/17 15:11:19 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
15/02/17 15:11:19 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 7.0605 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
15/02/17 15:11:19 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
15/02/17 15:11:19 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
15/02/17 15:11:19 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

Any insights is much appreciated.

Please let me know if any more information is expected.

Thanks,
Pras

Answer (score 1):

Check whether jdbc driver is under $SQOOP_HOME/lib or not. You need JDBC driver to be present in sqoop lib directory. Sqoop will load classes from jar files that are under this location to perform MR job.